# Pass header parameters in javascript document.link.href call

Tags: javascript

I am implementing browser javascript code.

I have defined a link as follows

```
document.location.href ="/cssp_authorization?user_name="+ Ext.JSON.encode(user_name);
```

When a user clicks on the link the call gets directed to the /acspp_authorization page. However, I need to also pass a header information in this GET request. How can I do that?

Comment: Header info as in HTTP header info?  You can't do that with just a link (or `location.href`).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest switching to POST requests instead of GET and use [setRequestHeader](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) method of the standard XMLHTTPRequest:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","cssp_authorization",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("My-Header","My-Value");
xmlhttp.send("user_name="+ Ext.JSON.encode(user_name));
```

You could use [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if jquery is your preferable option.

Comment: Why do you suggest a POST when a GET would do the job equally well? Also GET and POST have semantic value and are not interchangable.

Comment: There are many reasons, some explained here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get

Comment: If you read carefully you'll see why the POST request you're offering is considered invalid.

Comment: Can you please pin point the exact place you are referring to?

Comment: Maybe it's better if I explain it. OP is not processing any form or data whatsoever. OP only wants to **get** a resource and send a custom header along with the request. Therefor POST is invalid.